# Pasar un String a un arraylist e imprimir dicho arraylist sin existe el código del String

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo de momento 2 clases Películas y Principal:
En películas se encuentra:

public class **Peliculas** {

```
private String idpelicula;
private String nombre;
private int cantidad_ejemplares;

public Peliculas() {

    this.idpelicula = "";
    this.nombre = "";
    this.cantidad_ejemplares = 0;
}

public Peliculas(String idpelicula, String nombre, int cantidad_ejemplares) {

    this.idpelicula = idpelicula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cantidad_ejemplares = cantidad_ejemplares;

}
```

En **principal**

public class Principal {
        ArrayListlista_peliculas = new ArrayList();

```
    lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A10", "Elysium", 10));
    lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A20", "Remember the Titans", 2000));
    lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A60", "The Expendables 3", 23));

    do {

        System.out.println("*********MENU*********");
        System.out.println("1.-Alquilar una película.");
        System.out.println("2.-Devolver película.");
        System.out.println("3.-Listar alquileres.");
        System.out.println("4.-Salir");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingresa una opción: ");
        opcion = sc.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("******************LISTA DE PELICULAS******************\n");
            Peliculas arraypeliculas[] = new Peliculas[lista_peliculas.size()];
            lista_peliculas.toArray(arraypeliculas);
            for (Peliculas e : arraypeliculas) {

                System.out.println(e);
            }

            // Ingresar idPelicula
            System.out.println("Introduce el código de la pelicula a alquilar:");
            String codigo_alquiler = sc.next();

            break;
```

}

Lo que intento es en la variable código_alquiler, si ingresa el código de la película, que se encuentra dentro de un Arraylist ejm:
**lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("**A60**", "The Expendables 3", 23));**

Si ingresa el "**A60**", me muestre solo la lista de dicho elemento e intentado con contains, y no lo muestra estoy practicando arraylist y aun no lo tengo claro del todo. Agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Podrias subir todo el codigo mejor

Answer (score 1):

Si es un ArrayList, entonces Contains busca que el ArrayList contenga el mismo objeto, no hay forma de hacer que busque solo por el código (para esto habria que cambiar el modelo y armar un diccionario o un set).

La forma de buscarlo, debería ser recorriendo el ArrayList entero y preguntando si algún código de la película coincide hasta que se encuentre o se complete el recorrido del Arraylist.

Espero sirva!